# android receiver stops after clean ram

Tags: android

I have a gcm receiver, but it is not working before restarting phone and after clean memory. What should i change to guarantee receiver is always working?

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.example.diyet.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

<activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
<receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.plugin.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />,
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what does "clean ram" mean?

Comment: sory for my english, i mean "after i kill running applications"

Comment: well if you kill your application of course it wont work, that is why you should never kill applications

Comment: but after i open it, it not starts again. Only main activity starts

Answer (score 0):

if u want to start your receiver manually then use

`registerReceiver(receiver)` inside your activity

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know anything about GCM but if I get you right you have one of the following possibilities

If your GCMIntentService is custom, you can make this Service `STICKY` So the OS restarts it after a Crash. To do this you have to return `return Service.START_STICKY;` in your onStartCommand Method.

Also you can Register for the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` to get your Service started right after device is Booted.

If you want to prevent the Service to Crash, when the App Crashes you have to put it in another Thread. This can be achieved by Setting an custom Process Name in the Manifest

```
android:process="com.gigatronik.presenter.serialport.SerialPortListenerService"/
```

I will edit this answer, if you can give me more information on your Problem, since I never used GCM